# Viewpager2 onPageSelected is called when keyboard opens

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I have implemented `Viewpager2` and have 2 fragments in it, whenever i open the keyboard the `onPageSelected` of `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback()` is called and the selected page is first shown to the first one and then shifts to the second one

```
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            selectedPos = position
            if (position == 1) {
                ivBackVp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                progress.progress = 100
                if (userType == Const.TYPE_PARENT) {
                    tvStepDescription.text = getString(R.string.create_profile_step_two)
                } else {
                    tvStepDescription.text = getString(R.string.create_profile_step_two_child)
                }
                tvNext.text = getString(R.string.done)
            } else {
                ivBackVp.visibility = View.GONE
                progress.progress = 50
                if (userType == Const.TYPE_PARENT) {
                    tvStepDescription.text = getString(R.string.create_profile_step_one)
                } else {
                    tvStepDescription.text = getString(R.string.create_profile_step_one_child)
                }
                tvNext.text = getString(R.string.next)
            }
        }
    })
```

i have tried setting `configChanges to keyboard in the manifest` but it also failed. Please do help me with a logical reason of why it must be calling and what should i do to solve this one.

Comment: The problem probably occurred because of `ViewPager` being resized. I think it can be an issue in library, because VP2 is in beta. You can report it here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:561920%20status:open

Comment: @Ufkoku Thanks for that link, i found the same problem reported before and acknowledged by google as well. So we can just wait for an update to solve this issue for now.

Comment: has this been resolved? I have been struggling with this for far too long now...

Comment: Did anyone find solution? The problem still exists...